# Django: Filtering Annotated Results

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I want to create a nav list that contains all of the statuses I have in my status model, example: Today, Tomorrow, Waiting, Scheduled, Trash

Simple enough.  I then want to display the number of tasks assigned to each status, thanks to SO, also simple:

```
Status.objects.all().annotate(Count('task'))
```

This nicely creates a list of all of my statuses and a number the number of tasks assigned to each:

> Today (1)
>   Tomorrow (1)
>   Waiting (0)
>   Scheduled (2)
>   Trash (7)

The trick with all of this is now how to filter the above values so that they only reflect the current logged in user.  Adding a filter to the queryset seems to remove any zero statuses which makes sense.  I want those zero statuses though.  My current idea involves `Q()`:

```
Status.objects.filter(Q(task__user=1) | Q(task__user__isnull=True)).annotate(Count('task'))
```

This does not work.

Any ideas?

**Edit for Yuji**

```
Status.objects.all().annotate(Count('task'))
```

Gives:

> Inbox (3)
>   Today (0)
>   Next (1)
>   Waiting (0)
>   Scheduled (1)
>   Later (0)
>   Someday (0)
>   Archives (0)
>   Trash (0)

Great but 1 of those inbox tasks and scheduled are for another user.  Ok, so let's try filtering.

```
Status.objects.filter(task__user=current_user).annotate(Count('task'))
```

> Inbox (2)
>   Next (1)

Works!  Sorta....  My (as I called them) zero'ed out statuses aren't there.  I should say, any status that doesn't have a task associated with it as that currently logged in user does not show up.  I want it to show up.

Comment: Should be `Count('task_set')` instead of `Count('task')` since you don't have `related_name` set on `Task.status`.

Comment: `Count('task_set')` throws me an error.  Count('task') works, what is task_set suppose to do?

Comment: This field is [auto-generated by Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) whenever you use a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Maybe first get a distinct of all the task values(I hope it's indexed!) and use that list as a base and add the counts you found for the task values that actually do exist.  Something like: Status.objects.values('task').distinct() will give you all of them.  If your task types were foreign keys to another table you would have a neater solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a count of all Task objects belonging to the User by count.

```
Status.objects.filter(task__user=current_user).annotate(Count('task'))
```

What do you mean adding a filter removes any zero statuses?

Adding the user filter would get all Task objects that are associated with the User, regardless of Status  (0 or what have you).

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I thought you were referring to the Task.Status field. Your example should work. Wait nevermind. Upating post

Comment: Yea, sorry.  I have never been good at explaining problems :)  I want create a list of all of the statuses and if they just so happen to have any tasks assigned to one of those statuses to return that as well.

Comment: Damnit, nooo! I'm getting confused :3

Comment: I want `Inbox (3) Today (0) Next (1) Waiting (0) Scheduled (1) Later (0) Someday (0) Archives (0) Trash (0)` for the current user.

Comment: I know, I know. I'm saying my brain is failing atm. Will continue thinking about this...

Answer (score 0):

Does `Status.objects.annotate(Count('task')).filter(task__user=current_user)` work?

What you want is, at the SQL level, a `LEFT JOIN` or somesuch, with the `Status` table on the left, rather than an `INNER JOIN`.  Not sure how that interacts with annotations, though.

Brute force is `[stat.filter(task__user=current_user).count() for stat in Status.objects.all()]` if all else fails, but that's N queries instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Well... the only way I think you can achieve this is with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s or `SUBQUERY`s... I have no idea on how to express left outer joins in django, so I'll go with the `SUBQUERY` path. The following will use `extra` with some handcrafted SQL, enjoy!

```
# you should have Task and Status imported
x = Status.objects.extra(select = {
    "task__count" : "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %(task_table)s WHERE %(task_table)s.%(task_status_id)s = %(status_table)s.%(status_pk)s AND %(task_table)s.%(user_col)s = %(user_id)d" % 
    {
        "task_table" : Task._meta.db_table,
        "task_status_id" : Task._meta.get_field_by_name("status")[0].column,
        "status_table" : Status._meta.db_table,
        "status_pk" : Status._meta.pk.column,
        "user_col" : Task._meta.get_field_by_name("user")[0].column,
        "user_id" : 1

    }
})
```

Note that I'm using a lot of... undocumented features (for instance: Task._meta), these might break in the future (let's hope not)... but hey, they do the job.